# adding alt attribute to a banner image (opencart)

Tags: php, opencart, banner

On the website we have banners all over but non of them have any alt text.

Below is the code for, any pointers as to how i can solve this issue? I was thinking maybe having the alt as the image name if possible so need to find a way to echo it.

Any other suggestions?  I have 8 banners and don't mind manually adding the alt text for each banner if possible

```
<?php if ($module_title){ ?>
<div class="box-heading"><?php echo $module_title; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="box rich_banner grid_holder">
<?php foreach($sections as $section){ ?>
<div class="banner_<?php echo $columns; ?>">
<div class="image zoom_image_container"><img class="zoom_image" alt="" src="<?php echo $section['image']; ?>" />
<?php echo $section['description']; ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

would this be the section of variable below?

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleCosyoneBanner extends Controller {
    public function index($setting) {


        if(empty($setting['module_title'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')])) {
            $data['module_title'] = false;
        } else if (isset($setting['module_title'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')])) {
            $data['module_title'] = html_entity_decode($setting['module_title'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }

        $data['columns'] = $setting['columns'];

        if (isset($setting['sections'])) {        
            $data['sections'] = array();

            $section_row = 0;

            foreach($setting['sections'] as $section) {
                $this->load->model('tool/image');

                if (isset($section['block'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')])){
                    $block = html_entity_decode($section['block'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                } else {
                    $block = false;
                }

                if (isset($section['thumb_image'])){
                $image = 'image/' . $section['thumb_image'];
                } else {
                $image = false;
                }


                $section_row++;

                $data['sections'][] = array(
                    'index'   => $section_row,
                    'description'   => $block,
                    'image' => $image
                );
            }

            return $this->load->view('extension/module/cosyone_banner', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you print_r the $sections variable, and edit your post with the result?

Comment: Sorry i am new on this any ideas where this would be defined?

Comment: As all my banner point to my categories, using category name would also be fine.  I tried adding ="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" in alt but that didn't work.  I guess this is a variable in category and not for banners.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use the description in your alt, I think for what's available that is the best solution.

```
<div class="image zoom_image_container"><img class="zoom_image" alt="<?php echo $section['description']; ?>" src="<?php echo $section['image']; ?>" />
```

Comment: Ok thanks will give it a try when am back home, is it possible to make individual alt manually for each banner maybe?

Comment: well that would not work unfortunately as i am using the description for something else as below.

<a href="/speciality-and-branded" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;"></a>

Comment: How easy is it add another description box which can be used for something else?  Sorry if its stupid question as my knowledge in php is limited.